# Error while deploying hudson war into jboss 6

Tags: hudson, jboss6.x

I'm new to Hudson. I'd like to use Hudson with JBoss6. I put hudson.war into the deploy folder of JBoss6, but when I start the server it shows the error reproduced below. What should I do for the proper deployment?

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\jboss-6.0.0.20100429-M3\server\default\deploy\hudson.war (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106) [:1.6.0_13]
        at org.jboss.vfs.spi.RootFileSystem.openInputStream(RootFileSystem.java:55) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.openStream(VirtualFile.java:236) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:459) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
        at org.jboss.vfs.util.automount.Automounter$RegistryEntry.mount(Automounter.java:237) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
        at org.jboss.vfs.util.automount.Automounter$RegistryEntry.access$000(Automounter.java:208) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
        at org.jboss.vfs.util.automount.Automounter.mount(Automounter.java:117) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
        at org.jboss.vfs.util.automount.Automounter.mount(Automounter.java:77) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.CR5]
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.AbstractVFSArchiveStructureDeployer.performMount(AbstractVFSArchiveStructureDeployer.java:145) [:2.2.0.Alpha4]
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.AbstractVFSArchiveStructureDeployer.mountArchive(AbstractVFSArchiveStructureDeployer.java:128) [:2.2.0.Alpha4]

Comment: please help me to solve this issue. :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used JBoss, but the problem is clearly that some other application is holding your hudson.war . It looks like you are running JBoss on Windows, so this is what I'd do:

Download and run [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) -> Find -> Find Handle or DLL -> enter `hudson.war` into *Handle or DLL substring* box -> push *Search*  . It will probably show some app other than JBoss using the file (or it can be another instance of JBoss app that you did not kill properly). See what it is and whether you can close it.

(If you click on that line it will actually navigate to that app in the main window, you can kill it by right-clicking on it and choosing the appropriate menu item).

Comment: The  error listed above resolved.Now it shows a class cast exception.why it so?

Comment: Please post it as a new question - make sure to reproduce the new log.